# Use UIDocumentInteractionController to share files

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I use UIDocumentInteractionController to share files in my app's sandbox to the WeChat app. After sharing it with the WeChat app, a popup window will appear. The first line will display "Return Application", I clicked it, but could not return to my app. What else do I need to do? Thanks.

Comment: Add some code how you are presenting `UIDocumentInteractionController` so that can get some context on your issue.

Comment: NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];\n  
 self.document = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];\n  
self.document.delegate = (id)self;\n  
BOOL canOpen = [self.document presentPreviewAnimated:YES];

Comment: Is this the thing you're looking for? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app

Comment: Have you set URI & callback url setting fro your app ?

Comment: @ Nikola Markovic  @CodeChanger  tks, In Xcode, in Target->info->URL Types, I 
already set the thing, but it does not work. Just use UIDocumentInteractionController to share pdf file,  it does not work.